# ANOVA post-hoc multiple comparisons for unequal variances

Tags: anova, spss, multiple-comparisons, heteroscedasticity, post-hoc

I am running one-way ANOVA to determine whether several groups have differing means. I also run post-hoc multiple comparison to determine which means are different.  The problem is that I need to have it showed which sets of groups are not different (like REGWQ test does). The problem is that Levene's test shows that the data I use do not have equal variances, thus, I cannot run REGWQ test.

Is there any alternative to REGWQ for cases when equal variances are not assumed (except for non-parametric K-W test)?

I use SPSS but can also try R.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then yes SPSS has [Unequal Sample Sizes and Unequal Variances (Post Hoc Tests algorithms)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/alg_posthoc_unequalvar.htm): Games-Howell, Tamhane's T2, Dunnett's T3, and Dunnett's C. You would have to figure out yourself which one to use given your data, design and research objectives.

As for R, you can run the Games-Howell test in the [`userfriendlyscience`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/userfriendlyscience/userfriendlyscience.pdf) R package  (see also [here](https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/games-howell-test) for an example) and [Dunnett's T3](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DTK/DTK.pdf). For the other tests there don't seem to be packages/functions available for R.

Comment: Dear @Stefan, thanks for your answer. I am more interested, though, in a special REGWQ post-hoc test and its alternative. As far as I know, REGWQ can only be applied to situations, when equal variances are assumed. Then it groups variables with similar means (i.e. those that are not different) (https://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/statistics/local_copies_of_sources_Cardinal_and_Aitken_ANOVA/MultipleComparisons_3.htm#b12.). My question is if there is an _alternative to REGWQ_ in cases when _equal variances are not assumed_ (because there is no such option in SPSS).

Comment: @Tomas Oh I see, so the mean differences are first ordered from smallest to largest and then tested in a step-wise fashion. Sorry I don't know of any test that would do that for samples where the assumption of equal variances is not met. However, instead of testing this assumption with a formal test (e.g. Levene's test), you should inspect you data visually. Depending on your sample size these tests may or may not be very useful (e.g. [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92829/is-visual-inspection-the-only-way-to-compare-large-datasets)).